# The Integral value of $\lfloor\frac{a}{30}\rfloor$

Tags: triangles

The altitudes from the angular points $A$, $B$ and $C$ on the opposite sides $BC$, $CA$ and $AB$ of ***$ABC$*** are $210$, $195$ and $182$, respectively. Then what is the the value of $\left\lfloor\frac{a}{30}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. What have you tried?

Comment: I know that side is inversely proportional to altitude and proportionality constant is twice the triangle area.

Comment: Is $a$ the length of the side opposite angle A or the area?

Comment: yes. It is side length opposite to vertex A.

Comment: Have you drawn a picture?  I found two right triangles with the hypotenuse each side of the triangle.  You know one leg of each.  Making variables for the pieces of each side and writing the Pythagorean equations looks like it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For a $\triangle\text{ABC}$:

$$
\begin{cases}
\left|\text{A}\right|^2=\left|\text{B}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{B}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\angle\alpha\\
\\
\left|\text{B}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{C}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{C}\right|\cos\angle\beta\\
\\
\left|\text{C}\right|^2=\left|\text{A}\right|^2+\left|\text{B}\right|^2-2\left|\text{A}\right|\left|\text{B}\right|\cos\angle\gamma
\end{cases}\tag1
$$

By setting $\left|\text{A}\right|=210$, $\left|\text{B}\right|=195$ and $\left|\text{C}\right|=182$, we get:

$$
\begin{cases}
210^2=195^2+182^2-2\cdot195\cdot182\cdot\cos\angle\alpha\\
\\
195^2=210^2+182^2-2\cdot210\cdot182\cdot\cos\angle\beta\\
\\
182^2=210^2+195^2-2\cdot210\cdot195\cdot\cos\angle\gamma
\end{cases}\tag2
$$

So:

$$
\begin{cases}
\angle\alpha=\arccos\left(\frac{27049}{70980}\right)\\
\\
\angle\beta=\arccos\left(\frac{39199}{76440}\right)\\
\\
\angle\gamma=\arccos\left(\frac{49001}{81900}\right)
\end{cases}\tag3
$$